# The Inverse of a function with logic operators

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would one be able to tell whether or not a function has an Inverse? I've got  a question in my discrete mathematics/ combinatorics class that asks whether or not the following function has an Inverse and if so give the Inverse.

{(p, q) | q =¬p}

where p and q are elements of the set {T,  F}  where T is tautology and F is contradiction.

I know for regular xy functions, it has an Inverse if it is one to one and also how to find the Inverse.  But how would I apply that knowledge to this question?

Comment: You have to prove, that the relation you described is [injective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) and [surjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function).

Comment: The above is an injective function so that means it has an Inverse but will that be p= ¬q?

Comment: A function $f$ has an inverse function, iff $f$ is injective and surjective. So, if you proved both, you can be sure that there is an inverse function. To get the inverse function, remember that for all $(a,b)\in\{(p,q)\mid q=\neg p\}$, the reverse tuple $(b,a)\in\{(p,q)\mid q=\neg p\}^{-1}$

Comment: First, you have to understand what particular function $\{(p,q)\mid q = \neg p\}$ denotes. Let's call the function $f$. What is $f(T)$? What is $f(F)$?

Comment: As @Danny mentioned, you have to show that the function is onto (i.e., surjective), but that's easy. The inverse function is indeed $f^{-1}(x) = \neg x$. You say you can find the inverse of numeric functions, and you can use the same technique for logical functions.

Answer (score 1):

> The above is an injective function so that means it has an Inverse but will that be p= ¬q?

Yup. We have $f(T)=F, f(F)=T$ so $f^{-1}(F)=T, f^{-1}(T)=F$, which means that $f^{-1}(q)=\lnot q$. In this case $f^{-1}=f$: they're the same function.